# meaning of $[x]_{m(x)}$ in congruence classes modulo a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

In talking about congruence classes modulo a polynomial, my text mentions the following: "... we may think of $F[x]/(m(x))$ as $F[\alpha]$, the set of polynomials with coefficients in $F$ evaluated at the congruence class $\alpha = [x]_{m(x)}$."

So what does $[x]_{m(x)}$ mean? Does it refer to all $b(x)$ such that $b(x) \equiv x \pmod {m(x)}$ ?

Hopefully this question is clear in this brief context...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What textbook are you using? The more context you provide the more likely you'll receive an optimal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that,

$\left[ x \right]_{m(x)} = b(x) + \left(m(x)\right)$, where $b(x) \in F[\alpha]$ s.t. $deg(b(x)) < deg(m(x))$

[Check here for more notes on Modular Arithmetic and Congruence Classes with Polynomials](http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/wdj/book/node74.html)